# In Xcode 3.2.5, can I update a file or project reference in Xcode when it moves on disk?

Tags: xcode, file, reference

In many software packages that work with references (even iTunes), you can move files on disk, and then update the reference in the software.  In Xcode version 3.2.5, I can't figure out how to do this.

I could open the project file in a text editor and change the path to the file or project that I moved on disk, but I'd prefer to not to.

I could just move the file back to where is was on disk, but let's assume I moved it on purpose.

I could remove the reference from the project and add a new one, but that is unnecessary steps, and won't re-add any build dependencies or actions that I had set up for that resource.

So, is there a way to just update the reference from within Xcode?  Have I missed a simple menu option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 3.2.5 won't track relocated files automatically, unless that file is within a [folder reference](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/xcode/xcode-folders-and-the-file-system-part-1.html) (however folder references have other limitations).

In Xcode 3.2.5, you can update the reference by:

1. Selecting the file
2. Right click, Get Info (or Cmd-I)
3. Select General Tab
4. Click "Choose..." button at the top of the window.

Comment: Perfect.  I was not expecting to update a reference under "Get Info", so I didn't dig around in there.  Thanks!